# Rename files based on parent folder...but with different variations

Tags: python

I'm very new to python and stackoverflow but so far loving the way I can use it for small daily tasks at work!

I just got put on a project where we have to match a set of files to a company's standards - basically renaming files to match the company's naming nomenclature.

The current folder structure is as follows:

- Working Drawings Folder

  - M001 - People Hall

    - People Hall-1_Final.vsd
    - People Hall_Final-2.vsd
    - People Hall-3_Final.vsd

What I need to change them to is:

- Working Drawings Folder

  - M001 - People Hall

    - M001_People_Hall_Final-1.vsd
    - M001_People_Hall_Final-2.vsd
    - M001_People_Hall_Final-3.vsd

As you can see, the current files we have might have "-1_Final.vsd" and some others might have "_Final-2.vsd". There are about 400 "M001 - People Hall" folders with different "M" numbers and names. And some folders might only have 1 file, some folders might have 10 files!

I've tried so many ways to do this (and read the similar questions on this website) but I'm only about a month in to learning python so this would be the most complex thing I've had to do so far - so I think most of the stuff involved here is way over my head! I've read a book on python which gives me a basic outline of importing os, and appending, but I could really use some help getting this python script together so I can learn from it.

If anyone has any suggestions, I would be extremely appreciative!

Thanks so much,
Dave

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to "normalize" file names by splitting them into words, then filtering out numbers, them joining back.

```
import os
import re


def cut_and_sort(name):
    # "foo_bar-3-baz" -> ["foo", "bar", "baz", "3"]
    parts = re.split(r'[\s\._-]', name)
    result = []
    result.extend(p for p in parts if not p.isdigit())  # words first.
    result.extend(p for p in parts if p.isdigit())  # numbers last.
    return result


def normalize_name(name):
    # cut out the.vsd part.
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(name)
    # recombine the name from parts. 
    return '_'.join(cut_and_sort(name)) + ext
```

Now you can:

```
>>> normalize_name('People Hall_2-Final.vsd')
'People_Hall_Final_2.vsd'
```

I hope it's a good starting point for you.

Comment: Hi @DavidBlack! I hope you were able to figure out the rest.

Comment: `import os
directory = r'C:\Users\david\OneDrive\Documents\Python\The Self Taught Programmer\20150178 Tufts'
parent_directory = os.path.dirname(directory)

vsdfiles = [os.path.join(root, name)
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory)
            for name in files
     if name.endswith((".vsd"))]

for files in vsdfiles:
    if any("-1" in files for files in vsdfiles):
        os.replace("-1","")
        os.rename(files, path + files)

    if any(" " in files for files in vsdfiles):
        os.replace(" ","_")`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to format my progress like you have... But that's what I have so far. I have a flowchart written in front of me of the steps I need to take in order to get the product, but I just can't seem to get very basic stuff to happen for me! Any criticisms (which I'm sure is everything!) is greatly appreciated! @Greg

Answer (score 0):

If 9000's answer does not work, I would try something along the following lines:

```
import os
directory = <<INSERT DIRECTORY PATH HERE>>

parent_directory = os.path.dirname(directory)

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    os.rename(filename, parent_directory + '_' + filename)
```

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks so much for your response! Please refer to my reply to 9000 to see my progress. Hopefully I'll get a chance to post what I have so far tonight!

Thanks again,
Dave